# Remainder Adds Up

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the estimated population for the next five years but I want an integer as the answers since we don't have a fraction of a person. I do understand that the remainder of lost people add up eventually however I don't know how to add up all the lost people and add them to each year's population. Can someone help?

```
#Current population
p=312032486
#Sec-to-Yr
t=(60*60*24*365)
#One birth every 7 seconds
b=t//7.0
#One death every 13 seconds
d=t//13.0
#One new immigrant every 45 seconds
i=t//45.0
#Remainder of Left Out People
r=(t%45.0)+(t%13.0)+(t%7.0)
#Change Per Year
c=(p+b-d+i)

pop1=round(c+r, 0)
pop2=round((pop1+c+(r*2)), 0)
pop3=round((pop2+c+(r*3)), 0)
pop4=round((pop3+c+(r*4)), 0)
pop5=round((pop4+c+(r*5)), 0)
print(pop1, pop2, pop3, pop4, pop5)
```

Comment: In your haste to ask your first question (welcome to Stack Overflow!), you forgot to take the [Introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You also forgot to mention which programming language this is.

Comment: I recommend you do exact division. If you want you can do rounding when you actually print the values, but it's not really necessary, IMO.